# Software Center Crashing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-center

ello! I discovered the problem while trying to update my trezor bridge. When I launch the software center, it crashes immediately and I get this...

```
>2018-12-23 17:37:34,594 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2018-12-23 17:37:34,811 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2018-12-23 17:37:34,812 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2018-12-23 17:37:34,844 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 261, in open
    self._cache = apt.Cache(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 152, in open
    self._depcache = apt_pkg.DepCache(self._cache)
SystemError: E:The package trezor-bridge needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
2018-12-23 17:37:35,460 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
```

I read all the similar posts but haven't found a solution, and other people's errors seem different than mine. Tried uninstalling and re-installing the software center, and noting changed. Ran an update, and nothing changed. Any suggestions??

Comment: From the command line, does `sudo apt-get update` work?

Comment: yes. the only error I receive at the bottom is this one W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.